# Correct proxy path in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

we have two servers, A and B. Server A is accessed worldwide. He has nginx installed. That's what I have in conf:

```
location /test {
  proxy_pass http://localserver.com;
}
```

What it should do, is translate the addreess http://globalserver.com/test (that is server A) to internal server address http://localserver.com. However, it does append the location path, that is, itries to look for http://localserver.com/test, which is not available at all. How can I make the proxy pass to the correct address, throwing out the last part in the location?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That should work. Nginx should strip the '/test' path on the upstream local server. So what I can say is that is not the cause. To make it a bit better, try this:

```
location /test/ {
  proxy_pass http://localserver.com/;
}
```

The 2 slashes I added at the first 2 lines will avoid mistakenly match '/testABC' and send the wrong request to the upstream local server, for example.

Do you have a

```
proxy_redirect
```

line in the same location block? If your upstream local server has redirects, then a mistake on that line will cause an issue like you described.

[**UPDATE**] Found the root cause why the original config didn't work and mine works: nginx does NOT replace URI path part if the proxy_pass directive does not have a URI path itself. So my fix of adding a slash (slash is treated as a URI path) at the end triggers the URI path replacement.

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

> If it is necessary to transmit URI in the unprocessed form then directive proxy_pass should be used without URI part
>
> ```
> location  /some/path/ {
>   proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```

Comment: Well the solution here is if I add at backslash (root path) at the end of my URI `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/` nginx won´t add the incoming path at the end?

Comment: Wow! still valid after 8 years

Answer (score 1):

try to add as specified here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass:

```
      proxy_pass http://localserver.com/;
```

Answer (score -1):

try rewrite

```
location /test {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/;
    proxy_pass http://localserver.com;
}
```

some helpful links...

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls