# nginx: No Such Resource

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to proxy forward a deluge-web client running at port 8002 to a location `/deluge` and leave rest of location `/` to serve a directory.

```
upstream deluge {
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/web;
                autoindex on;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /deluge {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://deluge;
        }
}
```

I verified if deluge-web is running:

```
root:~# ps -aux | grep deluge
root      7652  0.0  0.2  67896  2200 pts/0    S    23:20   0:00 sudo nohup deluge-web -p 8002
root      7653  0.0  2.2  72488 22832 pts/0    S    23:20   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluge-web -p 8002
root      7743  0.0  0.0  10464   936 pts/0    S+   23:31   0:00 grep --color=auto deluge
```

Visting `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/` works fine. But visiting `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/deluge` throws a 404 error:

```
No Such Resource

No such child resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer!

[Correct proxy path in nginx.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353935/correct-proxy-path-in-nginx-conf)

You want slashes on the ends of location and proxy_pass so it doesn't redirect the location too.

```
pasted from answer-

    location /test/ {
      proxy_pass http://localserver.com/;
    }

nginx does NOT replace URI path part if the proxy_pass directive does not have a URI path itself. So my fix of adding a slash (slash is treated as a URI path) at the end triggers the URI path replacement.

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

If it is necessary to transmit URI in the unprocessed form then directive >proxy_pass should be used without URI part
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem is that the 'base' configuration in Deluge's web.conf does not work as expected. So you have to do URL rewriting in the reverse proxy, which your answer obviously doesn't do.