# Multiple DJANGO applications under single url

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm launching a couple of DJANGO instances under the same url. They all serve files over HTTPS. In order to save money for ssl certificates, I'm launching them under `mydomain.com/django1/` , `mydomain.com/django2/` etc. The redirection to the correct DJANGO instance is done in NGINX.

My problem is, how should I change the DJANGO urls to match this architecture? Or can it be done in `settings.py`?

Documentation: [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#s-how-django-processes-a-reques) and [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name) do not seem to give a clue, though I don't really understand the latter...

Thanks in advance!

DA

**EDIT 1**

This is the block from nginx.conf

```
location /django1/static/ {
    alias full_path_to_static/static/;
}

location /django1 {
    # We use python for this one
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_buffering off;
    uwsgi_pass unix:full_path_to.socket;
}
```

Comment: SSL certs are free now.  https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: I believe you don't have to change anything in the settings.py. From the application's perspective the root path / will just be mydomain.com/django1/ instead of mydomain.com

Comment: Despite that letsencrypt is a very good alternative - if you want to stick with this approach, please post your nginx configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct proxy path in nginx.conf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353935/correct-proxy-path-in-nginx-conf)