# Django + nginx + uwsgi how to use one domain to build multiple application?

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain, uwsgi

My question is how can I use one domain (mydomain.com) to build multiple django server?

This is my nginx.conf,

```
upstream django_myproject {
    server unix:///home/frank/myproject/haunyu.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mydomain.com; # This is my ow
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/frank/myproject/media;  
    }
    location /static {
    alias /home/frank/myproject/static;
}
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django_myproject;
    include     /home/frank/myproject/uwsgi_params; # 
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

I try to let location "/" replace to  location "/first_app"
like this

```
location /frist_app {
    uwsgi_pass  django_myproject;
    include     /home/frank/myproject/uwsgi_params; # 
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

Then I try to type domain/frist_app to browser, I got 404, My uwsgi also has no contact message.

Comment: Check the access log. You should see the sequence of requests that finish with the 404 response.

Comment: Why not put it under a subdomain like firstapp.mydomain.com? In you're attempt you'll and up writing workarounds in the urls.py and probably more places. Otherwise this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353935/correct-proxy-path-in-nginx-conf).

Comment: Subdomain is much easier to achieve then a different base url